Getting Error NG02200 while testing my Angular component
I am creating a dummy project for my learning, and hence reading data from session storage. I have to write test case for the following file:
TS File
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
existingUsers: User[] = [];

constructor(
private userservice: UserserviceService,
private routerService: Router
 ) {}
 ngOnInit(): void {
 this.existingUsers = JSON.parse(
   sessionStorage.getItem('usersData') || '{}'
  );

this.userservice.newUserSubject.subscribe((user:any[]) => {
  if (user.length >= 1) {
    this.existingUsers.push(user[user.length - 1]);
  }
});

sessionStorage.setItem('usersData', JSON.stringify(this.existingUsers));
}
}

HTML file
 <div class="container responsive-grid">
  <mat-card *ngFor="let users of existingUsers; let index = index">
    <mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-title>{{ users.name }}</mat-card-title>
</mat-card-header>
<mat-card-actions>
  <button (click)="editUser(index, users)">Edit User</button>
  <button (click)="deleteUser(index)">Delete User</button>
</mat-card-actions>
<br />
<mat-card-content>
  <br />
  <div>
    <strong><label for="name">Name</label></strong> {{ users.username
    }}<br />
    <strong><label for="username">Email</label></strong> {{ users.email
    }}<br />
    <div>
      <strong> Address</strong>
      <div>
        <strong><label for="street">Street</label></strong>
        {{ users.address.street }}<br />
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong><label for="suite">Suite</label></strong>
        {{ users.address.suite }}<br />
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong
          ><label for="city">City</label> {{ users.address.city }}</strong
        ><br />
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong><label for="zipcode">PinCode</label> </strong
        >{{ users.address.zipcode }}<br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-card-content>

Spec.ts File  for unit testing
  it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

this default test case if failing for the above code
Error Message
Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'.
         NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays.
         Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe?

I have tried to create a existingUser Array in Spec file

The problem is that in your ngOnInit() you are setting this.existingUsers to an empty object in case the session storage does not return any matching item. However, *ngFor expects an array. This is relevant for your test case, as the testing environment has an empty session storage by default. To fix it, just use empty array instead of empty object.
this.existingUsers = JSON.parse(
  sessionStorage.getItem('usersData') || '[]'
);

To have better type safety, you can also refactor the code a bit:
const storedUsers = sessionStorage.getItem('usersData');
this.existingUsers = storedUsers ? JSON.parse(storedUsers) : [];

Now TypeScript will warn you if you use {} instead of [].

I did the changes , but still the test case is failing

Is there any other part in your code where this.existingUsers is modified? Or are you mocking anything in your test case?

I was mocking existing user in spec file as well. I guess that was causing the issue. Removing that from spec file and also replacing [] for {} made this test case passed.
Thanks

can you explain, why mocking data in spec file were cause this test case to fail ?

Maybe I can if you add the code of your mocks

component.existinguser =[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Leane",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"address": {
"street": "Kulast",
"suite": "Apt. 556",
"city": "Gw",
"zipcode": "92974",
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Ervin",
"username": "An",
"email": "Sha@m",
"address": {
"street": "Victor",
"suite": "Suite 879",
"city": "Wisokyburgh",
"zipcode": "901",
}
}
]
fixture.detectchangae();
//then the test case...
